# how to install multiple packages in one line using conda?

Tags: python, conda

I need to install below multiple packages using conda. I am not sure what is conda-forge? some uses conda-forge, some doesn't use it. Is it possible to install them in one line without installing them one by one?  Thanks

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash-daq
conda install -c conda-forge dash-core-components
conda install -c conda-forge dash-html-components
conda install -c conda-forge dash-bootstrap-components
conda install -c conda-forge dash-table
conda install -c plotly jupyter-dash
```

Comment: Have you tried? Just give it a go, but yes, you can. Although packages from different channels will need to be installed separately I believe

Comment: Just one clarification to this answer, environment.yml doesn't work with conda install --file. You need to use conda env commands with environment.yml. for reference, see this [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6827)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Why some packages have to be installed through conda forge:

Conda official repository only feature a few verified packages. A vast portion of python packages that are otherwise available through pip are installed through **community** led channel called *conda-forge*. You can visit their [site](https://conda-forge.org/) to learn more about it.

### How to install multiple packages in a single line?

The recommended way to install multiple packages is to create a `.yml` file and feed conda this. You can specify the version number for each package as well.

The following example file can be fed to conda through `conda install --file`:

```
appdirs=1.4.3
asn1crypto=0.24.0
...
zope=1.0
zope.interface=4.5.0
```

To specify different channel for each package in this `environment.yml` file, you can use the `::` syntax.

```
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - bagit
  - conda-forge::beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: A question about multiple channels: what is the equivalence of `conda install -c C1 -c C2 A`? Do I specify both `C1::A` and `C2::A` in the `yml` file?

Answer (score 20):

I believe you can just list them all one after the other:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash-daq dash-core-components
```

Comment: Thanks but the last one doesn't use conda-forge. what does conda-forge do? Thanks

Comment: conda is a package manager, similar to pip, and conda-forge is a channel within that package manager. So if the last one isn't in conda-forge, you can try to install it using pip from within the anaconda prompt.

Comment: @roudan You will have to install `jupyter-dash` separately then.